# Linked list value pointed only changing inside function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in C:

```
struct Node{
    struct Node *next;
    void *data;
};
```

With an insert function:

```
void insert(void *p2Node, void *data)
{
    struct Node *newNode;
    struct Node **p2p2Node= (struct Node **)p2Node;
    
    if (newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node))) /* if successfully allocated */
    {
        newNode->data = data;
        
        if ((*p2p2Node) != NULL) /* if the list is not empty */
        {
            newNode->next =  (*p2p2Node)->next;
            (*p2p2Node)->next = newNode;
        }
        else
            (*p2p2Node) = newNode;

        p2Node = p2p2Node;
    }
    printf("Inside the insert: %s\n", (*p2p2Node)->data);
}
```

I called insert in `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    char *setA = "liquid ";
    char *setB = " lgd";
    char *setC = "sample";  
    struct Node *nList = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    insert(nList, setC);
    printf("2Get %s\n", nList->data);
    
    return 0;
}
```

No error or warning was reported, but **the value was only changed inside the** `insert`. Back to `main()` the linked list is still empty.

I do not understand: `nList` in `main()` is a void pointer. Inside `insert()`, `*p2Node` is not altered, I used `p2p2Node` to change the value `p2Node` points to, why is it not working? Did I mismatch the pointers? Is there a way I can make it work without modifying the parameter of `insert()`?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot just cast a parameter to pretend it was passed by reference.  I refer to this line: `struct Node **p2p2Node= (struct Node **)p2Node;`  If you want the _pointer_ value to be modified by the function, then the _parameter_ to the function must be a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @paddy Does that mean I should modify the pointer passed in, i.e. `nList`, to be a pointer of a pointer to a struct? I mean, a pointer to a pointer is still a pointer, it should be okay to be passed into `insert` as `void *p2Node`?

Comment: Based on the logic I see inside your function, the function's signature should be `void insert(struct Node **p2p2Node, void *data)` and when you call it for an empty list, `nList` should be NULL.  Then you call `insert(&nList, setC);`  You should also use `calloc` when allocating inside the `insert` function, _OR_ explicitly set `next` to NULL.  Currently, the value of the next-pointer on the first node inserted is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to insert values to the linked list.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};

struct node *root = NULL;
int len;

int main()
{
    append();
    display();

    addatbegin();
    display();

    addatafter();
    display();
}
```

Add values to the end of the list.

```
void append(){
    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp->data);
    temp->link = NULL;
    if(root == NULL) //list is empty
    {
        root=temp;
    }else
    {
        struct node* p;
        p=root;
        while(p->link != NULL)
        {
            p = p->link;
        }
        p->link = temp;
    }
}
```

Add values to the beginning of the list.

```
void addatbegin()
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data : ");
    scanf("%d", &temp->data);
    temp->link = NULL;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        temp = root;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->link = root;
        root = temp;
    }
}
```

Add value after a node

```
void addatafter()
{
    struct node* temp, *p;
    int loc, i=1;
    printf("Enter the location : ");
    scanf("%d", &loc);
    if(loc > len)
    {
        printf("Invalid input.");
    }
    else
    {
        p = root;
        while(i > loc)
        {
            p = p->link;
            i++;
        }
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter the data : ");
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);
        temp->link = NULL;
        temp->link = p->link;
        p->link = temp;
    }   
}
```

To display the linked list

```
void display(){
    struct node* temp;
    temp = root;
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("List id empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL){
            printf("%d -> ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```